# MongoDB method for storing time-series data

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, data-modeling, nested-object

What would the optimal method be to store time-series data in MongoDB or any NOSQL database?
As of now, I have it stored like this:

```
{
    "_id":{
        "$oid": "60eaa0e2126e154cf079067f"
    },
    "data": {
        "1626098400000":{
            "temp": 23.3,
            "humid": 0.75
        
        },
        "1626098410000":{
            "temp": 30.5
        },
        "1626098430000":{
            "humid": 0.85
        },
        "1626098440000":{
            "temp": 28.3,
            "humid": 0.65
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks,
Rohan

Comment: https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/building-with-patterns-the-attribute-pattern

Comment: How do you plan to query that data?

Comment: @prasad_ To start off, I would like to get the time instances when temperature/humidity was between a range or greater than a value.

Comment: @turivishal Thank you, will check it out. 
I am looking for storing time in milli-seconds.

Comment: You can refer [Query Documents](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-documents/), to start with.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @prasad_ . 
Is nested documents/objects the way to go ?

Comment: You store data to perform CRUD operations on it. How does your application use the data? What are the important queries? How much data? These generally influence the database design (or data model). See [Data Model Design](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/data-model-design/).

Comment: @prasad_
1. The application uses data to understand and find patterns in time intervals.
2. Important queries would be to find temp/humidity at a particular time instance, time when a temp/humidity is between a range, >, or <.
3.  Expecting 100,000 date objects per month, per sensor. For the time being, I have only two - temperature and humidity.

Comment: I can only suggest write some queries on your database - and figure how it works for you. It will give you a chance to review or change the design.

Comment: Alright. Thank you @prasad_